# Update a variable in another file

Tags: sed, variable

File1 is

```
var=10
```

File2 is

```
source File1

echo $var     #this displays 10 if I ran the shell.
```

What goes here? I can’t get sed to work because I can use the variable inside the sed command,

```
$ sed -i ‘s/echo $var/var=$((var+10))/‘ File1`
```

I’ve tried all different combinations. I know this is bad code but I don’t have a better why to explain.

```
source File1

echo $var # I want this to display 20
```

I would like to alter File1 from File2 so I can add 10 to the value. Changing the results from 10 to 20 at the end of File2.

I’m open to all work arounds. I’m trying to create a character sheet for Dungeons and Dragons that tracks my HP among other things.

Comment: Try `echo $(($var+1))`

Comment: sed is "not working" because the string `echo $var` does not appear in File1

Answer (score 2):

Note that your `sed` command is trying to do a substitution of the text `echo $var` in `File1`, but you have just shown that `File1` does not contain such a line.

To overwrite `File1` with a single line saying `var=20`, use

```bsh
echo 'var=20' >File1
```

To overwrite `File1` with a single line assigning the value `$((var + 10))` to the variable `var`, use

```bsh
printf 'var=%s\n' "$((var + 10))" >File1
```

or

```bsh
cat >File1 <<END
var=$((var + 10))
END
```

In the last example above, we perform the operation by means of a here-document that is expanded by the current shell before being written to the file using a redirection form `cat`.

The last two variations assume that the variable `var` has some (integer) value already.

---

Another way to interpert your issue is that you want to read the value of `var` form `File1` and then simply print that value with 10 added to it.  You would do that with

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

. ./File1
printf '%s\n' "$((var + 10))"
```

The `.` command is the standard command used for sourcing another file.  The `source` command is specific to `bash` and some other shells, but works (almost) the same.

You may also want to test whether the `var` variable is actually set, and output a diagnostic message otherwise.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

. ./File1

if [ "${var+set}" = set ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$((var + 10))"
else
    echo 'The variable "var" is not set' >&2
fi
```

---

If your D&D character sheet contains more values, and you want to update them individually, then I would probably not keep that sheet as a shell file that I source.  Instead, I would use something like YAML or TOML to hold the stats, and then a YAML or TOML parser (like `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) to read and update those stats.

Character sheet in YAML:

```yaml
characters:
  - name: Bard the cleric
    class: Cleric
    level: 45
    hp: 3
    backstory: >
      Bard was born in a small village
      east of the Great Lake.
      Etc.
  - name: Cleric the ranger
    class: Ranger
    level: 35
    hp: 5
```

Then, in some script,

```bsh
# Add 5 to "Cleric the ranger"'s hp (does in-place editing)
yq -y --in-place '.characters[] | select(.name == "Cleric the ranger").hp += 5' sheet.yml
```

---

A simpler variant than the above, which does not provide any of the richness of a structured document format, use the `bash` shell and its `declare -p` functionality to write out the variables that you want to save to file.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

source ./character  # contains variables hp and name

printf 'HP = %s\n' "$hp"

# change hp and write back to file
hp=$(( hp + 10 ))

declare -p hp name >./character
```

After running this, the file `character` might look like

```bsh
declare -- hp="15"
declare -- name="Ranger the warrior"
```

(if `hp` had been `5` from the start).  Note that the file is completely clobbered, so we need to write all variables to it, not just the ones we change.

Comment: +1. I like the yaml solution. it's good.   structured text makes sense for a character sheet.  A level 45 cleric with only 3 hp, though? should have at least 4. maybe even 5.

Comment: @cas That last fight was a bit tougher than expected, hence the low HP...

Comment: probably needs a max_hp field as well as current hp.

Comment: @cas I've been meaning to learn D&D properly, but I'm getting too old for that stuff. It would probably be easy to come up with a generic character sheet software with a YAML (or SQLite) backend for use in actual gameplay.

Comment: Yeah, that kind of software already exists.  [pcgen](http://pcgen.org/) for example is char sheet software for several versions of D&D (from original to current, including offshoots like pathfinder and OSR) and several non-D&D RPGs.    [Maptool](https://www.rptools.net/toolbox/maptool/) is map editing and on-line play software that users have written campaign templates for to support various kinds of character sheets.  Both programs are open source (written in java, iirc).   and lots of people have written spreadsheets for RPG character sheets.

Comment: btw, to really showcase the yaml solution, a shell wrapper that takes a few args (maybe with getopts) and runs yq with the right values in the right places....because, as great as tools like yq (and jq and xmlstarlet and other structured-text editors) are, they can be a PITA to construct a useful command-line for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`

file 1

```
$ cat file_1
var=10
```

file 2

```
$ cat file_2
source file_1
sed -i "s/$var/$((var + 10))/" file_1
source file_1
echo "$var"
```

**output**

```
$ ./file_2
20

$ cat file_1
var=20
```